# How to translate field names in Laravel validations?

Tags: laravel, validation, translation

It's easy to translate messages of validations in Laravel.
But I couldn't find out how to translate field names.

There is a ":attribute" placeholder in `validation.php` that will be replaced by the real field name which is usually English.

**English:** The "price" field is required.

**Italian:**

Il campo "price" è richiesto. <== WRONG

Il campo "prezzo" è richiesto. <== RIGHT

**French:**

Le champ "price" est obligatoire. <== WRONG

Le champ "prix" est obligatoire. <== RIGHT

**Persian:**

.مورد نیاز است "price" <== WRONG

قیمت" مورد نیاز است" <== RIGHT

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the file:

```
{project}/resources/lang/{your-locale}/validation.php
```

At the bottom you have this:

```
'attributes' => [],
```

You can add your translations like this:

```
'attributes' => [
    'price' => 'your translation'
],
```